# DoctrineDataFixtures not found travis build

Tags: symfony

В чём может быть проблема после коммита в гит Travis-ci всегда fail из-за

> Uncaught Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal
>   error: Class 'Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle'
>   not found in /home/travis/build/testapp/app/AppKernel.php:14

Хотя namespace в autoload есть в appKernel,

```
new Doctrine\Bundle\FixturesBundle\DoctrineFixturesBundle(),
```

Comment: loader может быть не загружает его?

Comment: причина была в том что в гит composer.lock не закомитил)